# Sign in user to google account in Windows Service (without browser and user actions)

Tags: c#, windows-services, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I am trying to get user tokens in windows service. Application know username and password, and each day is creating new events in user calendar.

For now, as workaround, I create another (desktop) app, just to get user tokens when I need it, but this requires action from user, and users are not signin to server every day to check that all processes are working properly.

Is there any way to sign in to google calendar api without this pop up browser and to get user credentials?

Comment: Have you checked this open issue from github samples using google api if authorization code without popup possible? - https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/288

Comment: Apart from the use of javascript, from what I understood after reading the thread, they worked on the solution to download the access token and not refresh the token that is needed. Although I do not want to believe that nobody tried to implement such functionality in some windows service. I also read about selenium, but it is not something that I can use. Ater I get refresh token I successfully refresh the token and load events, I only need a way to log in first time and possibly handle the case of errors with refreshing, resulting in re-calling of the login window.